# Nmos-bjt darlington pair dc bias. [Homework Help]

Tags: bjt, nmos

I have a homework assignment I need some help with.

I wanted to know if someone could tell me if I'm doing the dc bias calculations correctly, if not, could someone nudge me in the right direction.
I'm not talking about the ac analysis, only dc.

Here is the question
[image: question]
Here is my attempt
  [image: attempt]

Comment: +1 for the efforts even though it is HW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation mostly seems to be correct. The quadratic equation has the term "25000*Id^2" instead of "25*Id^2", but it is a typo since you have calculated reasonable Id values. Vs for Id = 1.23mA is fine. Vs for Id = 1.715mA would be 3.2V, not 5.1V.